# How to record the data based on user ID in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Hi guys I'm new in Oracle Apex and I want to record the data based on the user id in Oracle Apex. The application has two role which is employee and manager. I want to make if the employee login to their account, they can only see and update their own record. Besides that, the manager can see all the employee record. The record data already working but not based on the user id. Anyone know how to do that? Thank you

The table structure for record data

```
    CREATE TABLE  "TIMESHEET" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "NO" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "CUSTOMER" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DATE_" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "TIME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "WORKING_HOUR" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "PIC" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "TOPIC" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "REMARK" VARCHAR2(50),
        "APP_USER" VARCHAR2(255),  

         PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE
       )
    /
```

[Data record (not based userid)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NuGf.png)

[Data record (APP_User still empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztzno.png)

Comment: That's your table structure, not a SQL query. It's not clear from your question how timesheet records are linked to employees, but I would expect that the query you use to show the timesheet records should have a filter e.g. `where timesheet.app_user = :APP_USER` or something like that, to ensure that users can only see their own records.

Comment: sorry i mean table structure. where can i input  timesheet.app_user = :APP_USER? because i'm new in oracle apex @JeffreyKemp

Comment: I think you'll first need to understand and explain the data model. At the moment, you have not shown how your model indicates how a timesheet record is linked to a user account (the employee).

Comment: Yes, i think i haven't link the user account with the timesheet. I can't find any resource how to link it. Any suggestion? @JeffreyKemp

Comment: Well, without any understanding of your data model it's hard to be sure, but you might add `APP_USER VARCHAR2(255)` to your table.

Comment: I need to add APP_USER VARCHAR2(255) in the timesheet table ? @JeffreyKemp

Comment: well yes, that is what I suggested

Comment: What should i write in the PL/SQL? after adding the APP_USER VARCHAR2(255)? @JeffreyKemp

Comment: What PL/SQL? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't add the PL/SQL. Btw, for the APP_USER, we don't need to show it as a text fields right? @JeffreyKemp

Comment: I have tried to add APP_USER in timesheet table, and add the timesheet report (in the picture) can you check? The APP_USER column still empty @JeffreyKemp

Comment: So you've added the column, now you need to fill it with data. You need to work out where to source that data from, and do an update on the table.

Comment: One thing you can do is, for new records, have the column auto-filled with the user who created it. To do this, issue the following command to set a default on the column:
`alter table timesheet modify app_user default on null sys_context('apex$session','app_user');`

Comment: Then, in your timesheet report, add a filter to the query, e.g. `select ... from timesheet where app_user = :app_user`

Comment: when i'm trying to do "alter table timesheet modify app_user default on null sys_context('apex$session','app_user');" it shows error like this "invalid NOT NULL constraint specified on a DEFAULT ON NULL column". What should i do for that?

Comment: that means there is already some data in the table - you need to update APP_USER on the existing rows first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to record the user who created the record is to use a trigger on the table `TIMESHEET`. This will populate the column APP_USER you added after @Jeffrey Kemp's comment with the value of the user who did the update on insert.

```
create or replace trigger timesheet_biu
    before insert 
    on timesheet
    for each row
begin
    :new.app_user := coalesce(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user);
end timesheet_biu;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's work @Koen Lostrie